# OK to call dispatch_resume before dispatch_source_set_timer?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

Is it OK to call `dispatch_resume` before `dispatch_source_set_timer` for a timer dispatch source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, resumed timer sources that have never had `dispatch_source_set_timer()` called on them are considered disabled by the implementation (as a safety measure).

Best practice however is to initialize a timer that you don't currently need to fire with a next fire time of forever before you initially resume it

```
dispatch_source_set_timer(t, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER, 0);
```

and then to reconfigure the timer with a subsequent call to `dispatch_source_set_timer()` once the desired timer parameters are known.